# Xcode iOS Automatic Code Signing with com.apple.developer.passkit.pass-presentation-suppression

Tags: ios, xcode, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

I am trying to incorporate the com.apple.developer.passkit.pass-presentation-suppression entitlement into our project but Xcode is not able to generate a provisioning profile with this entitlement.

I am past the process of acquiring the suppression entitlment option for our account and we can manually create the provisioning profile with given entitlements.

The error from xcode is:

```
Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: <budle_identifier>" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.passkit.pass-presentation-suppression entitlement.
```

Also after trying to repair the provisioning profile in xfode, all of the profiles get invalidated in developer.apple.com portal (even the manual ones).

Have anyone had this kind of problem and managed to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple responded with information that automatic code signing is not available for use with this entitlement